# Iterating over dates with a bash loop in bash -- for (( ... )) not working correctly

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting

I am trying to create a list of dates. This script below works with simple dates with no spaces.

```
datestart=20130601
dateend=20130705

for (( date1="$datestart"; date1 != dateend; )); do
    date1="$(date --date="$date1 + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')";
    echo $date1;
done
```

When I use a data string like (which contains WHITE SPACE) datestart="2013-06-01 00:00:00" and a date format like +'Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

```
datestart="2013-06-01 00:00:00"
dateend="2013-07-05 00:00:00"
for (( date1="$datestart"; date1 != "$dateend"; )); do
    date1="$(date --date=""$date1" + 1 days" +'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')";        
    echo "$date1";
done
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: ((: date1=2013-06-01 00:00:00: syntax error in expression (error token is "00:00:00")
```

I think I am NOT quoting my variables correctly. I have twiddled and fiddled, and now I am here. How do I quote the variables correctly in a for loop?

Comment: The `$()` is a new parsing context. Double quotes inside it will not interact with double quotes outside it. So just quote the internal command as you would normally. Then *also* quote the entire `"$(...)"` expression when you need that.

Comment: Are you referring to line 4?

Comment: Yes, the `date1="...."` line. Your `...=""$date1"...` bit isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: `(( ))` is a math context. Only mathematical expressions are valid within it. When your strings are not math, you must not use `(( ))`. This is nothing to do with `for`.

Comment: ...thus, spaces aren't your problem as such -- *any* non-numeric value would behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
datestart="2013-06-01 00:00:00"
dateend="2013-07-05 00:00:00"

date1="$datestart"
while [[ "$date1" != "$dateend" ]]; do
   date1="$(date -u --date="$date1 tomorrow" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
   echo "$date1"
done
```

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/3YQV9d)

1. `((...))` is used for arithmetic operations only. Use `while` loop instead.
2. No need to use nested quotes for `$date`
3. Use `tomorrow` to get next date
4. Use correct `year-month-date` format while assigning next date to `date1`

Comment: This will be the accepted answer, but the other answers from Pasaba and Ghoti are good!

Answer (score 2):

No way, bash three-expression for loop expects aritmetic expressions. See this link:

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for

use a classic "while" loop instead.

**Addendum**

You can use seconds from epoch to allow arithmetics, like in:

```
datestart=$(date --date="2013-06-01 00:00:00" +%s)
dateend=$(date --date="2013-07-05 00:00:00" +%s)
for (( date1=$datestart; date1 != $dateend; date1+=86400 )); do
    date --date=@$date1
done
```

but care with days that has not 86400 seconds.

Comment: Okay this looks good. So my understanding is that Bash for loops do NOT like variables with spaces?

And the reason is that the for operator cannot operate on such complex forms/types? I.e. it wants them in a simple form?

Comment: This class of loops doesn't likes strings, with or without spaces. About the addendum, you must evaluate if it is valid for your objective or you must take special care with the days that has no 86400 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about your quotes being off.  You had:

```
date1="$(date --date=""$date1" + 1 days" +'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')";
```

but you're doing in and out of your double quotes in very weird ways with this. A quick solution might be to switch to single quotes, which do not isolate variables if they are inside double quotes:

```
date1="$(date --date="'$date1' + 1 days" +'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')";
```

As for the other part ... let's just review what's on the bash man page:

```
for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done
      First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated according to
      the  rules  described  below  under  ARITHMETIC EVALUATION. ...
```

And if you check the `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section of the man page, you'll see that it does *not* include the sorts of tests that /bin/test or `[[ ... ]]` can run.  Those are covered in the next section of the man page, `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`.

If you want to use a `for` loop, then @pasaba's suggestion to use epoch seconds is what I'd go with also, in order to stick with arithmetic.  Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

datestart="2013-06-01 00:00:00"
dateend="2013-07-05 00:00:00"

e_start=$(date -d "$datestart" '+%s')
e_end=$(date -d "$dateend" '+%s')

for (( date1=$e_start; date1 < $e_end; date1+=86400 )); do
    echo -n "$date1 "; date -d "@$date1" '+%Y-%m-%d'
done
```

To account for leap years and leap seconds and the like, you can put your trust in the Linux `date` command, and evaluate `$date1` in the loop as you originally did:

```
for (( date1=$e_start; date1 < $e_end; )); do
    date1=$(date -d "$(date -d "@$date1") + 1 day" '+%s')
    echo -n "$date1 "; date -d "@$date1" '+%Y-%m-%d'
done
```

The nested `date` commands are required because Linux's `date` command doesn't allow you to use relative dates ("+1day" or "tomorrow") when the origin date is specified as an epoch with `@`.  (I'd love to know if I'm wrong about that.)

---

I realize that your question is tagged "Linux", but I'll note for future searches that this is a non-portable (Linux-only) use of the `date` command, so if you want this script to run in FreeBSD, NetBSD, OSX, etc, you'll need to review their usage.  The following works in FreeBSD:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

datestart="2015-06-01 00:00:00"
dateend="2015-07-05 00:00:00"

e_start="$(date -jf '%Y-%m-%d %T' "$datestart" '+%s')"
e_end="$(date -jf '%Y-%m-%d %T' "$dateend" '+%s')"

for (( date1 = $e_start; date1 < $e_end; )); do
    date1=$(date -j -v+1d -f '%s' "$date1" '+%s')
    echo -n "$date1 "; date -jf '%s' "$date1" '+%Y-%m-%d'
done
```